# Changing text to image with php variables

Tags: php, html

I am building a slot machine and am trying to create a shop where you can buy images to replace the text. If I click the button it just resets my money to zero and doesn't replace any text with images. How can I fix this without compromising any functionality or adding hundreds of lines of code?

```
<html
<?php
  //shop
    if (isset($_POST['shop']))
    {
      if ($credit = 50 or $credit > 50)
      {
        $credit = $credit - 50;
        strtr($str, array(
    'Zero' => "<img src=img/Zero.png />",
    'Bar' => "<img src=img/Bar.png />",
    'Double Bar' => "<img src=img/DoubleBar.png />",
    'Triple Bar' => "<img src=img/TripleBar.png />",
    'Cherry' => "<img src=img/Cherry.png />",
    'Seven' => "<img src=img/Seven.png />",
    'Diamond' => "<img src=img/Diamond.png />",
    'Clover' => "<img src=img/Clover.png />",
        ));
      }
      else
      {
        $message = "You don't have enough money!";
      }
    }

<!-- display -->
<?php if (!$bust) { ?> 
<div id="slots">
 <?=join(' | ', $slot_result)?>
</div>
<br/>
<br/>                   
<?=$message?>
<?php } else { ?>
<?=$message?>
<?php } ?>
<br/>
  <br/>
  Total cash: €<?=$credit?>
    <form method='post'>
        <input type='submit' name='spin' value='Spin' />
        <input type='hidden' name='credit' value='<?php echo $credit; ?>' />
        <input type='submit' name='reset' value='Reset' />
        <br>  
        <br>  
        <input type='submit' name='shop' value='Change Style - €50' />
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: `$credit = 50` is an assignment, not a comparison. Furthermore the function `strtr` returns a string which you never output or assign to a variable.

Comment: Not a fix but note that the [<input>](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/dev/embedded-content.html#the-input-element), `<br>` and `<input>` tags do not use and do not need a closing slash and never have in any HTML specification.